# Linear equation AYB + Y = C

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

I have the following system of equations:

$AYB + Y = C$ with $Y\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}, B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, C\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

I know that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and semi-definited positive matrix. I want to obtain $Y$. Do you know a way about do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A suggestion that can be very useful is to have the definitions of the conditions imposed on the problem close by; not only think about the algebraic work of the problem. It would be nice if we could see his attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to calculate: $$\text{argmin}_{Y\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}}\frac{1}{2}\|A_c Y A_r^\top -B\|^2 + \frac{1}{2}\|Y-X\|^2$$ where $\|\cdot \|$ denotes the frobenius norm. If I derive, the solution $Y$ satisfies $A_cA_c^\top YA_r^\top A_r + Y = X+A_c^\top BA_r$ and I don't have any idea about how to clear $Y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), we have
$$
AYB + Y = C \implies\\
\operatorname{vec}(AYB + Y) = \operatorname{vec}(C) \implies\\
(B^T \otimes A + I)\operatorname{vec}(Y) = \operatorname{vec}(C) \implies\\
\operatorname{vec}(Y) = (B^T \otimes A + I)^{-1} \operatorname{vec}(C).
$$
In the above, $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). Because $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite, the matrix $B^T \otimes A$ is positive semidefinite which means that $(B^T \otimes A + I)$ is necessarily invertible.
The matrix $Y$ can then be attained by "unvectorizing", i.e. stacking the entries of the vector into an $m \times n$ matrix.